# Why do sounds work with Pygame before compiling with py2exe, but not after?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pygame

I have a project that I'm compiling with py2exe. After compiling, everything seems to be working fine except for the sound, which for some reason isn't playing anything except a single pop sound in place of the actual sound.

I know that relative paths are working, since all my other files (images, data-files, etc) are being loaded without any problems relative to the location of the application, and I'm not getting any error messages in the console (I compile with it showing, rather than with just the Pygame window alone).

This is likely a path problem more than a Pygame problem, or possibly I'm missing a .dll but I don't know what the exact cause of this problem is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing the sounds to .wav seemed to fix the problem. I tested many different other solutions, but this was the only one that seemed to actually work.